# Can't change/append data (integers) from python to .json file

Tags: python, json, pygame

I am currently making a save/load state of my game. I am using dictionaries and .json to save my data to a file. I am trying to add coins to the overall player statistics. Whenever the player collects the coins, they need to be saved to the player stats file. However, once I reload the game, the stats are back to their base ones. I have tried saving and loading back the data, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
import json
import sys
pygame.init()

DARK_GREY =  58, 58, 58

coins_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))
screen.fill(DARK_GREY)
tile_size = 50


class Level:
    def __init__(self, data):
        # Creating a list for the tiles
        self.tile_list = []

        # Loading block images
        dirt_block = pygame.image.load(r"Blocks\dirt_block.png")
        grass_block = pygame.image.load(r"Blocks\grass_block.png")
        invisible_block = pygame.image.load(r"Blocks\invisible_barrier.png")
        platform1_block = pygame.image.load(r"Blocks\platform_block1.png")

        row_count = 0

        # Assigns the values in the array with certain properties
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1: # Dirt Block
                    pass
                if tile == 2: # Grass Block
                    pass
                if tile == 3: # Invisible Barrier Block
                    pass
                if tile == 4: # Platform Block
                    image = pygame.transform.scale(platform1_block, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    
                    image_rect = image.get_rect()
                    
                    image_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    image_rect.y = row_count * tile_size

                    tile = (image, image_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)

                if tile == 5: # Coin
                    coin = Coin(col_count * tile_size + (tile_size // 2), row_count * tile_size + (tile_size // 2))
                    coins_group.add(coin)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    def draw(self):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])


level_data = [
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 3],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4, 3],
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4, 3],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
]


world = Level(level_data)


class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        pass

    def draw(self, display):
        display.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, level, health, damage, coins, skill_points):
        super().__init__(r"Knight\Stand Up\stand_up_10.png", x, y)

        # Player stats
        self.level = level
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.coins = coins
        self.skill_points = skill_points

        # Health system attributes
        self.current_health = 100
        self.maximum_health = self.health
        self.health_bar_length = 100
        self.health_ratio = self.maximum_health // self.health_bar_length

        # Idle image setup
        self.idle_image = self.image

        # Character attributes used when moving left and right, as well as jumping
        self.speed = 6
        self.jump_speed = 12
        self.y_speed = 0
        self.jumped = False

    def update(self):
        dx = 0
        dy = 0

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.facing_left = True
            dx = -self.speed
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.facing_left = False
            dx += self.speed
        else:
            if not self.facing_left:
                self.image = self.idle_image
            else:
                self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.idle_image, True, False)

        if key[pygame.K_UP] and not self.jumped:
            self.y_speed = -self.jump_speed
            self.jumped = True

        # Checks and applies gravity
        self.y_speed += 1
        if self.y_speed > 15:
            self.y_speed = 15
        dy += self.y_speed

        # Checks and applies collision
        for tile in world.tile_list:

            # Detection in the x direction
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x + dx, self.rect.y, self.player_width, self.player_height):
                dx = 0

            # Detection in the y direction
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + dy, self.player_width, self.player_height):
                if self.y_speed < 0:
                    dy = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
                    self.y_speed = 0
                elif self.y_speed >= 0:
                    dy = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
                    self.jumped = False

        # Updates movement
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

    def save_to_json(self, filename):
        # Creating a dictionary to store all the data there
        player_dictionary = {'level': self.level, 'health': self.health, 'damage': self.damage, 'coins': self.coins, 'skill_points': self.skill_points}

        # Writing the data in a file using json
        with open(filename, "a+") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(player_dictionary, indent=2))

    def load_from_json(self, filename):
        # Reading the data in a file using json
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            player_data = json.loads(f.read())

        # Updating the attributes (stats) of the player by looking up the data in the dictionary
        self.level = player_data['level']
        self.health = player_data['health']
        self.damage = player_data['damage']
        self.coins = player_data['coins']
        self.skill_points = player_data['skill_points']

    def collect_coin(self, amount):
        self.coins += amount
        self.save_to_json(r"Player_stats.json")

    def execute_player(self):
        self.update()
        self.draw(screen)

def update_game():
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.display.update()


def demo_level():
    player.load_to_json("Player_stats.json")

    coin_image = pygame.image.load(r"Blocks\coin.png")
    coin_scale = pygame.transform.scale(coin_image, (50, 50))

    pygame.display.update()

    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if pause_button.is_clicked(event):
                navigation(DARK_GREY)
                pause_menu()

        # Overlay
        screen.fill(LIGHT_BLUE)
        world.draw()
        coins_group.draw(screen)
        screen.blit(coin_scale, (10, 80))
        coins_text = text(f"{player_stats['coins']}", 60, 80, 85)

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, coins_group, True):
            player.coins += 1
            player.save_to_json("Player_stats.json")

        # Player commands
        player.execute_player()

        # Updating the screen
        update_game()
```

Comment: Maybe your issue is, that you use the `a+` option when opening the file:

```
with open(filename, "a+") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(player_dictionary, indent=2))
```

This will append to the file.  If you do this multiple times, you will end up with invalid json.  I'm not sure, whether your game engine "swallows" a `JSONDecodeError`. Instead, use `w`.  When posting your question, it would be helpful if you could try to post only the necessary code.  In your case, if you could try to reproduce the issue by writing a class that only has a `save_to_json` and `load_from_json` method.

Comment: Fixed the mistake and the code seems to be working right now. Much appreciated for the help! Will make sure to post only the relevant code next time.

Comment: glad I could help.  For future reference, I just posted that as answer; could you please accept it, so that if anyone is interested in the solution they can just go to the accepted solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `a+` with `w` in the `with open(filename, "a+")` part.  `a+` instructs python to append to an existing file, which results in an invalid json file after saving twice.